# Restkit 0.20 CoreData error "Can't find model for source store"

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

I am trying to configure RestKit with CoreData. I get and error with "Can't find model for source store". I was using the configurations from the Restkit RKTwitterCoreData example. I found some similar posts on stack overflow where people say to delete the database but I don't know how to do this, am running on my phone, not the simulator. I also tried to do a Product:Clean but same error.

```
 2014-05-18 12:29:16.489 What my life could be[7006:60b] I restkit:RKLog.m:34 RestKit logging initialized...
2014-05-18 12:29:17.259 What my life could be[7006:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:], /Users/Pro/Desktop/ios app/What my life could be/What my life could be/AppDelegate.m:161
2014-05-18 12:29:17.262 What my life could be[7006:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to add persistent store with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)" UserInfo=0x15d7fc40 {URL=file:///var/mobile/Applications/2E1DA997-E54E-4CE3-AC62-6552445D77CF/Documents/JustD.sqlite, metadata={
NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 479;
NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
    ActivityEntity = <fdd7d538 648131cf 2fe3b684 bd55169e 85a7cee4 cbec3080 94202e4c 26b97889>;
    PriorityEntity = <74cd93d0 00ade70c ef4d0ea3 f177762d 7d342720 7aba6945 d83ee02d 96a2135c>;
    UserDataEntity = <2ffd8aec e7c1dacc 23e14fdd 400b60c0 5a1cd9a8 07fe6138 4d0e5a30 8e0c6e28>;
};
NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
    ""
);
NSStoreType = SQLite;
NSStoreUUID = "B1BC3FFF-F727-49E4-A44F-5C5216C58226";
"_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;}, reason=Can't find model for source store}'
*** First throw call stack:(0x2ec07e83 0x38f646c7 0x2ec07d55 0x2f5b00af 0xf37bb 0x313fcaad 0x313fc4f3 0x313f6b41 0x31391a07 0x31390cfd 0x313f6321 0x3387676d 0x33876357 0x2ebd2777 0x2ebd2713 0x2ebd0edf 0x2eb3b471 0x2eb3b253 0x313f55c3 0x313f0845 0xf3bc5 0x3945dab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException(lldb)
```

The part of code to config the store. I deleted the CoreData template default code, got error both ways. Note: I am not sure how the "importer importObjectsFromItemAtPath:...." works.

```
#ifdef RESTKIT_GENERATE_SEED_DB
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelInfo);
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/CoreData", RKLogLevelTrace);

NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success = RKEnsureDirectoryExistsAtPath(RKApplicationDataDirectory(), &error);
if (! success) {
    RKLogError(@"Failed to create Application Data Directory at path '%@': %@", RKApplicationDataDirectory(), error);
}
NSString *seedStorePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"JustDid.sqlite"];
RKManagedObjectImporter *importer = [[RKManagedObjectImporter alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel storePath:seedStorePath];
[importer importObjectsFromItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"activities" ofType:@"json"]
                          withMapping:activityMapping
                              keyPath:@"activity"
                                error:&error];
[importer importObjectsFromItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"users" ofType:@"json"]
                          withMapping:userMapping
                              keyPath:@"user"
                                error:&error];
BOOL success = [importer finishImporting:&error];
if (success) {
    [importer logSeedingInfo];
} else {
    RKLogError(@"Failed to finish import and save seed database due to error: %@", error);
}

// Clear out the root view controller
[self.window setRootViewController:[UIViewController new]];
#else
/**
 Complete Core Data stack initialization
 */
[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];
NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"JustD.sqlite"];
NSString *seedPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"RKSeedDatabase" ofType:@"sqlite"];
NSError *error;
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:seedPath withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];
NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);

// Create the managed object contexts
[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

// Configure a managed object cache to ensure we do not create duplicate objects
managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
#endif
```

Comment: try this it helped me http://stackoverflow.com/a/7626401/2050181

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have changed the version of your core data model and not asked core data to try to migrate automatically or provided a migration explicitly. So, as core data loads it detects the version mismatch and aborts.

Initially, delete the app from your device and reinstall and everything should work again. You would need to do this each time you change the data model.

Obviously it isn't a good idea to go to the App Store like that so you should research auto migration and it's constraints and (if required) explicit migration.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the database, just remove the sqlite file which should be at the address /var/mobile/Applications/2E1DA997-E54E-4CE3-AC62-6552445D77CF/Documents/JustD.sqlite
considering you logs

In a console:
rm /var/mobile/Applications/2E1DA997-E54E-4CE3-AC62-6552445D77CF/Documents/JustD.sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured your seed database is added to the Build Phase : Copy Bundle Resources?

I've just had the same problem for hours, and in the end it was as simple as that. Even though looking in the simulator-deployed app package, the seed sqlit file *was* there, but for some reason the managedObjectStore couldn't find it, but returned the “Can't find model for source store” error rather than, "Cannot find the seed data file" which would have been more helpful!