# adding a field to database without crashing the existing appstore app

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, app-store

I have a published app in the appstore. Recent changes to the app require me to add an extra field in the CoreData db.

If i do this without altering the other fields, will the update be succesful?

If not, how can i add a field to the db without damaging the app for the clients that already had the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Core Data Migration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Introduction/Introduction.html) to do this. You should be able to do it with [Lightweight Migration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweight.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008426-SW1), which means it can be done automatically.

This is covered very well in a number of tutorials and examples. [Here is a link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310216/implementation-of-automatic-lightweight-migration-for-core-data-iphone) Look at the accepted answer to that question.

Here is another one: [Can I use “Automatic Lightweight Migration” if my already release v1 didn't have a versioned Core Data model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497284/can-i-use-automatic-lightweight-migration-if-my-already-release-v1-didnt-have) That should set your mind at ease.

[Here is a tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/core-data_schema-versioning-and-lightweight-migrations/) that is a little easier to digest.

I have used automatic lightweight migration, and it is painless for the type of change you are describing.

Comment: Thank you Jim! I will look at the links and come back with a feedback :)

Comment: I have added some more links to my answer. It really is straightforward to do. Good luck.